# Using eigen with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I am relatively new to C++ and CMake and trying to use the [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library inside my current CMake project but I simply can not get it to work.

I searched trough Stackoverflow and Google but did not find a solution which worked for me.

**My current directory structure**

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── bin
├── build
├── main.cc
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── (other files)
│   ├── infra
│   │   └── (other files)
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── eigen (clone of the git repo)
│   │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       ├── Eigen (source files)
│   │       └── (other files) 
│   └── util
│       └── (other files)
│       
└── tests
    └──  (other files)
```

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES $ENV{CC} gcc PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES $ENV{CXX} g++ PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/bin)
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/build)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

project(myProject VERSION 0.0.1)

#For Testing
include(CTest)
enable_testing()

SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cc)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_run ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(src)
add_subdirectory(src)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_run ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib)
```

**./src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib)

# Clone Eigen
set(EXTERNAL_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/)
if(NOT EXISTS ${EIGEN_DIR})
    find_package(Git REQUIRED)
    execute_process(
            COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} clone https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror ${EXTERNAL_DIR}eigen
    )
endif()

    set(HEADER_FILES
           myHeaders
    )

    set(SOURCE_FILES
            mySources
    )


    include_directories(lib/eigen/Eigen/)

    add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
```

For compiling I am using `gcc` and `g++` both in version 7.3.0_1 installed with Home-brew.

Since it's a header only library I assumed that it is sufficient to only use `include_directories()`. I also tried to use the official approach mentioned at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html, but this didn't work either.

With the current configuration I am getting a lot of errors which look like this (just a small excerpt):

```
    **/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:18:8: error: 'traits' is not a class template
 struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
        ^~~~~~
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:18:15: error: 'Matrix' was not declared in this scope
 struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
               ^~~~~~
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:18:15: note: suggested alternative: 'atoi'
 struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
               ^~~~~~
               atoi
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:18:75: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
 struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
                                                                           ^
In file included from **/evsr/src/infra/random_projection.cc:9:0:
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:179:27: error: expected template-name before '<' token
   : public PlainObjectBase<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
                           ^
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:179:27: error: expected '{' before '<' token
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:428:32: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 6)
 typedef Matrix<Type, Size, Size> Matrix##SizeSuffix##TypeSuffix;  \
                                ^
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:441:1: note: in expansion of macro 'EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS'
 EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 2, 2) \
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**/evsr/src/lib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:449:1: note: in expansion of macro 'EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES'
 EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(int,                  i)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe someone faced this or a similar problem and knows a answer to this. I am happy for every little note.

Comment: [Read following manual](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already tried this approach but it gives me the following error: `CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
`

Comment: While not the best style, your `CMakeLists.txt` files are clearly picking up Eigen. Something else is causing a cascade of errors to the snippet that you pasted. Build your project verbosely (ie: `make VERBOSE=1`) and fix your errors from the top down. If you need help, update your question with **all** the errors from the the first file that generates errors.

Comment: Also note that example linked to by @VictorGubin implies that Eigen has been installed on your system, either via a package-manager or Method #2 in Eigen's [INSTALL](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/master/INSTALL) file.

Comment: @nega Thanks for your comment. What do you mean with not the best style ? What could be improved ?

Comment: For instance, look at CMake's [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) for pulling in Eigen and [compiler features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html) for setting your C++ standard.

Comment: Note that the git mirror to Eigen is deprecated. The new one (Dec/2023) is `https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the absolute path to the `Eigen` header files in my `src/CMakeLists.txt`.

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/eigen/)
```

I am not exactly sure why this resolved the issue but it did.

Comment: You may have been going too deep with the extra "Eigen" in your original call to `include_directories()`